# Different Number Ranges as Variables in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I've been wondering this for awhile but I've often been in situations where I have folders or files named with the following convention:

1. 1R143D1B
2. 2R143D1B
3. 3R243D1B
4. 4R343D1B
5. 5R343D1B

Where the first number (1-5) would represent, for example, a scan. The second number immediately after the 'R' (1, 1, 2, 3) would represent a day. The 43D1B is a subject number.

I'm constantly in situations where I need to get into multiple subject folders (e.g. the only thing changing in the naming conventions is the '43D1B' to other subject values like '44U2A') named like this and have often thought there would be ways like 'for' loops so I could code something that allows me to generate these values without hardcoding the cp (or any other) command.

So instead of hardcoding, for example, `cp /home/1R143D1B/1R143D1B.file /newfolder` and doing this 50+ times I was hoping to be able to maybe make the first value (the scan value) a for loop or array variable and the second (day value) value another variable so I could do something like `cp /home/${var1}R${var2}${subject}/${var1}R${var2}${subject}.file /newfolder`

But whenever I think about this logically I'm not sure the best way to go about it because the convention above is set that way - Scans 1 & 2 always are on day 1, scan 3 is always on day 2, and scans 4 & 5 are always on day 3 so the number 1-5 are not all associated with the numbers 1-3 so I don't know if a loop would work and I'm not sure what else would be appropriate.
Could anybody speak to another way to go about this?

Comment: Why can't you just use wildcards? As in `cp /home/?R?"$subject"/?R?"$subject".file /newfolder`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a better set of variables for your loop, e.g. `1R1 2R1 3R2 4R3 5R3`.